# Adding breakpoint with windbg does not work

Tags: .net, windbg

I want to add a breakpoint to the following constructor:

`!Name2EE *!System.Windows.Forms.Application+MarshalingControl..ctor`

I have loaded my application using WinDgb and executed the following commands:

```
.reload
CTRL + Shift + F5 to restart
sxe ld:clr
sxe ld:clrjit
F5 to start debugging
.loadby sos clr
sxe ld:System.Windows.Forms
F5 to continue debugging
```

Now when the application stops, I tried the follwing command:

```
!Name2EE *!System.Windows.Forms.Application+MarshalingControl..ctor
```

But instead of the address, it outputs modole names:

```
0:000> !Name2EE *!System.Windows.Forms.Application+MarshalingControl..ctor
Module:      00007ffbf1de1000
Assembly:    mscorlib.dll
--------------------------------------
Module:      00007ffb95494148
Assembly:    MyApplication.exe
--------------------------------------
Module:      00007ffbeb981000
Assembly:    System.dll
```

How can I get the address so I can add a breakpoint? Using WinDbg Preview, I was also not able to add the breakpoint using the GUI feature for adding a breakpoint.

Edit:
When running my application and pausing it, the command above will return the JITTED address. Do I need to use another `sxe` command that is called when all modules have been loaded?

Comment: The problem is: when the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly is loaded, the code is not jitted yet. Another `sxe` does not necessarily help. Some code may never be jitted (e.g. if not run). You need a solution which works when the code is still unjitted.